# My Niece is turning 4 and would like to give her BTC. What is the best way to give/store long-term?

Tags: storage

My niece turns 4 next month and I'd like to give her a fraction of a Bitcoin for her birthday.  What is a good way to do this so that she can hold on to it for 10 years or so?  Should I just store in a wallet myself and then give it to her later on?  As far as I know, her parents are not familiar with Bitcoin.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the safest medium on which to store my wallet/private keys?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/2245/what-is-the-safest-medium-on-which-to-store-my-wallet-private-keys)

Comment: On the link I just provided, Stephen Gornick suggests using the paper wallet generator on bitaddress.org. I've used it myself. I'd recommend printing multiple copies of it for storing in multiple locations, unless you already have a secure location like a bank deposit box.

Answer (score 2):

As a gift to a child, I'd recommend something more tangible than paper, such as a [Casascius](https://www.casascius.com/) coin or gold-plated bar. Yeah, it's more than a fraction of a bitcoin, but the load-it-yourself option might be more affordable.